# How would you find the Original ID, First ID and Last ID of a chain?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**PLEASE DO NOT MARK THE QUESTION AS DUPLICATE WITHOUT READING IT. I DID POST A SIMILAR QUESTION BUT THE STACKOVERFLOW COMMUNITY MEMBERS ASKED ME TO REPOST THE MODIFIED QUESTION SEPARATELY AS THE SOLUTION IS MUCH MORE COMPLICATED GIVEN A SMALL, SUBTLE MODIFICATION.**

Suppose you have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Data
(
  ID INT,
  CXL INT
 )

 INSERT Data (ID, CXL)
 VALUES
 (1, NULL),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 2),
 (5, 3),
 (6, NULL),
 (7, NULL),
 (8, 7);
```

The column CXL is the ID that cancels a particular ID. So, for example, the first row in the table with ID:1 was good until it was cancelled by ID:2 (CXL column). ID:2 was good until it was cancelled by ID:3. ID:3 was good until it was cancelled by ID:5 so in this sequence the last "GOOD" ID was ID:5.

**For each ID, I would like to find the "GOOD" ID and the original ID of EACH chain.** So in this example it would be:

```
ID   | Original ID | Latest GOOD ID
 1          1              5
 2          1              5
 3          1              5
 5          1              5
 6          6              6
 7          7              8
 8          7              8
```

Here's a fiddle if you want to play with this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b794f/1

Comment: Is the assumption you can't change the schema?  Recursion isn't typically a database's strong suit.

Comment: @Matthew - yes, that is a correct assumption - I can't change the schema, this table has been around for a very long time and became quite big.

Comment: I sense a CTE coming.

Comment: @Jodrell and you would probably be right... This is my SQL weakness...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT ID AS Parent, ID, CXL, 0 AS level
   FROM Data
   WHERE CXL IS NULL

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT c.Parent AS Parent, d.ID, d.CXL, level = level + 1
   FROM CTE AS c
   INNER JOIN Data AS d ON c.ID = d.CXL
)
SELECT ID, Parent AS OriginalID, t.GoodID
FROM CTE AS c
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT ID AS GoodID
   FROM CTE AS c2
   WHERE level = (SELECT MAX(level) FROM CTE WHERE Parent = c.Parent)
         AND c2.Parent = c.Parent
)  t(GoodID)
ORDER BY Parent
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d63d6/5)

Comment: you're the master. I just couldn't figure out how to put your previous answer and this problem together. Thank you!

Comment: This query took forever to run because my Data table was huge. So just modified your CTE query to use CTE first and then join on to the bigger table for better performance. For some reason our sql server 2008R2 didn't figure it out (maybe we need to rebuild statistics again)